# Method to update type of marker of scatter point

Tags: python, matplotlib

My question is if exist any method to update the type of marker of scatter points. For example the marker could change in dependence from direction of point move (it could be "v", "^", "<" or ">").

Answer (score 0):

A scatter plot is a `PathCollection`. You can update the paths of that collection with the path of a `MarkerStyle`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.markers import MarkerStyle

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter([0,1,0,-1],[-1,0,1,0], marker="o")

def make_path(m):
    ms = MarkerStyle(m)
    return ms.get_path().transformed(ms.get_transform())

markers = ["v", ">", "^", "<"]
sc.set_paths([make_path(m) for m in markers])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I think my problem is a little bit more complicated. I added part of a code to the post. Do you know hot to make markers changing in every iteration.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if you call that in an animation or not.

Comment: So I made it how is shown in the attached code, but it doesn't work properly. The marker is not changing with every iteration, but what  every generation of points.

Comment: I rolled back the question. This answer answered the original question just fine (a How-to-question). The edit contais a non-runnable code (so I cannot answer it) and turned it into a debugging question. You can ask a new question with your debugging problem (but make sure to use a [mcve]).